# Snowflake - Dynamic secure views - putting a second filter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to implement Snowflake Dynamic secure views by adding a second clause which will check the current_user, and grant them access to the rows in the shared table based on the IDs they have been mapped to see. For instance, if I'm sharing data with a "customerA" with multiple entityIDs, and the user is an "employeeA" working there, he/she should only be able to see the data for a particular entity, and not the whole list. Here is my entitlements table:

Table Name = Entitlements

| Customer_Name | Customer_ID | Snowflake_account | entity_id | snowflake_user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust1 | ABC | UN1234 | ENTITY1 | abc@cust1.com |
| cust1 | ABC | UN1234 | ENTITY2 | def@cust1.com |
| cust1 | ABC | UN1234 | ENTITY3 | ghi@cust1.com |

Here is my secure view definition:

```
create or replace secure view cust1_entities as
select sft.company_name,sft.company_id, sft.entity_id,sft.revenue from supplier_fact_table sft
join entitlements e 
on sft.company_id=e.customer_id
 and sts.SUPPLIER_ENTITY_ID=e.entity_id
 and e.snowflake_account = current_account()
 and e.snowflake_user = current_user();
```

So, if a user abc@cust1.com logs into the reader account, he/she should only be able to see rows belonging to entity_id=ENTITY1. However, my secure view is not working as intended, and showing me the entire dataset for all the entities. Please advise what I am missing here.

Thanks!

Test case described in the question

Comment: Hi , did you check if you can use Snowflake's inbuilt feature called Row access policy, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-row-intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is not working for you is that when you use `current_user()` in a secure view across a share (to the reader account), the result is always `NULL`.  Per the docs:

> Granting access on a secure UDF or secure view that contains this
> function to a share is allowed. When the secure UDF or secure view is
> accessed from the data sharing consumer account, this function always
> returns a NULL value.

Since you are sharing the secure view and the user/roles on the consumer side of the share differ from the provider side, you'll need to use a different function to accomplish this.

Comment: Note - if you can provide more details on the relationship between your users, roles, reader accounts, and shares to your entitlements, then the community could better help you find the right functions to leverage.